# Typescript and jquery-ui - what am I doing wrong

Tags: jquery, typescript, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use jquery and jquery-ui and typescript and having trouble getting it to allow the jquery-ui objects.

I used npm to install jquery and jquery-ui.

```
npm install --save jquery
npm install --save jquery-ui
```

In my typescript code, I add this:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui';
```

Then I try to create a dialog:

```
$("#my-id").dialog({ modal: true, etc, etc });
```

In VS Code, "dialog" gets flagged with this:

```
Property 'dialog' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'
```

So I looked around and found types for jquery-ui from DefinitelyTyped - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jqueryui

So I tried that:

```
npm install --save @types/jqueryui
```

Then I add this to the code:

```
import 'jqueryui'
```

Oddly (to me), the types are in "jqueryui" where jquery-ui itself is "jquery-ui" with the hyphen.

This makes the error above go away.

Then I run:

```
gulp bundle --ship
```

I get:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jqueryui'
```

I suppose my questions are:

1. Why doesn't it see the types for jquery-ui? Does it not include them for typescript? Why do I need @types/jqueryui separately?
2. How do I resolve not being able to build when I include jqueryui OR build without it and have it not kick out with an error on "dialog"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thank God, I just encountered this problem
and accidentally managed to fix it.
Maybe you can try this.

Set the properties of compilerOptions.paths in tsconfig.json
Add "jquery-ui"

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "jquery":["node_modules/@types/jquery/index"],
      "jquery-ui":["node_modules/@types/jqueryui/index"]
    }
  },  
}
```

Example

```
import 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui';

export class XXXXX {
  onClickVersions() {
    let r1 = $("#dialog-versions")
    if (r1.length == 0){
      $("<div id='dialog-versions'></div>").appendTo($("body"))
      setTimeout(() => {
        r1 = $("#dialog-versions")
        r1.dialog()
      }, 1);
    } else {
      r1.dialog()
    }
  }
}
```

In fact, I noticed that if you do not set compilerOptions.paths
Although the compiler gives an error message
but because jquery and jquery-ui are installed
but the program can still run (the dialog can still be displayed successfully)

Also, Although the extension of the declaration file is .d.ts, the paths value cannot be added to .d.ts

Error Code

```
paths": {
      "jquery-ui":["node_modules/@types/jqueryui/index.d.ts"]
    }
```

Also, the key in paths should be "jquery-ui", not "jqueryui":
because the path is node_modules/jquery-ui.

The key in paths should be the name of the package in node_modules
Not any name will do, and not the name of the @types folder

(I experimented by renaming node_modules/jquery-ui to node_modules/jqueryui.
then paths must be jqueryui instead of jquery-ui)